# Justify-content: space-evenly not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a responsive navbar with three items in the same container in the middle as shown below.

[image: What the navbar should look like]

For some reason the ul items are not being space evenly and it is showing me this:

[image: The 3 li items are not spaced evenly]

I used these lines of code:

```css
nav {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Home">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
</nav>
```

I appreciate any help and apologize if this post is unclear; I'm still new to this website.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wdfk98u0/

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to fix the issue was changing the "ul {...}" item in css to "nav ul{...}". Hopefully this can help out someone else in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

`space-evenly` or `space-between` will work!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5% auto;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li+li {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Learn More</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="">Sign Up</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```